# Proper way to send imageData[] with Quizlet API for images and Python3 requests

Tags: python, json, api

I'm building flashcards for learning names on one's team. The implementation is an integration between Slack and Quizlet; pulling name and photo from Slack and putting it into a private Quizlet set. I just upgraded to premium last night, so I should be able to upload images.

I'm using Python3 on OSX and have successfully authenticated. I know this because I was able to **successfully** make a set of cards via the API (https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/api-list), using this code:

```
url = 'https://api.quizlet.com/2.0'
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + data["access_token"]
}

def create_set():
    #POST /sets - Add a new set
    payload = {
        'title':'test0',
        'terms': names, #names is a preassembled list
        'definitions': pictures, #as is pictures
        'lang_terms': 'en', 
        'lang_definitions': 'en',
        'visibility': 'password',
        'password': 'secret_password'
    }
    call = requests.post(url+"/sets", headers=headers, json=payload)
    return call
```

Now that I'm able to put names, and even the links of the Slack profile photos onto the flashcards, I'm at a loss with the posting of the images. This is my code:

```
def upload_photos():
    #POST   https://api.quizlet.com/2.0/images  Upload one or more images
    url = 'https://api.quizlet.com/2.0'        
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + data["access_token"]}
    # ,'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'

    imageData = {
        'imageData': open(pictures[0], 'rb')
    }

    payload = {
        'imageData':pictures[0]
    }

    call = requests.post(url+"/images", headers=headers, files=imageData, json=payload)
    return call
```

I've tried the following:

- Playing around with the payload JSON. When I give it the whole pictures list, as opposed to just an element at [X]: `b'{"http_code":400,"error":"validation_errors","error_title":"Error","error_description":"The \"imageData\" parameter is missing or not valid.","validation_errors":["The \"imageData\" parameter is missing or not valid."]}'`
- Trying to manually add the multipart/form-data header. (See the commented out line). However, that gives me: `b'{"http_code":400,"error":"client_developer_error","error_title":"Error","error_description":"Expected a imageData parameter"}'`
- When I try to send the open file, I am told that JSON won't serialize that way, which makes sense.
- When I give just a list of the arrays of where the files are located, I get the same error about imageData being not valid.
- I tried every wrappers/Python packages for Quizlet that I could find, but all of them seem abandoned, with mostly lacking documentation.

To sum it up, I'd like to figure out how to get the profile pictures from Slack (whether it's downloaded images or the urls) to Quizlet's API. Thanks in advance for any input.

UPDATE: I played around the the sample curl request on the Quizlet API page and got it to work with the -f @ parameter. It seems like @ "lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388. This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get attached in the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field from a file." If anyone knows how to do the Python equivalent of the @, I think I'll be closer.